# Except being an invalid syntax

Tags: python

I asked a related question here about this. However, I still have one problem.

```
import sys 
import calendar

trueVal = 'yes' 
while trueVal ==  'yes' :  

 yy = int(input("Enter year: ")) 
 mm = int(input("Enter month: "))
 break
 except ValueError:
     print "Oops!  That was not an integer.  Try again..."

 print(calendar.month(yy, mm))#returns the result

 cmd=input("Would you like to view another calendar? Type yes if you do, no to exit program") 


if cmd != trueVal :
   sys.exit()
```

Apparently, my prof wants me to put an error message for users who input strings. So I put that except function but it doesn't recognize it.

Comment: `except` always needs a corresponding `try`...

Comment: You can't have an `except` block without a `try`

Comment: There is no need for `sys.exit` here; just break out of the loop, and let the program exit naturally.

Comment: The `print` statement indicates you are using Python 2.x; you should be using `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some errors in your code:

1. you didn't add "try" at the beginning of the block
2. even if you answered yes or no your program will have an error!

Here is the code you need, so you can get your deadline ;)

**Updated!** Because you are using Python 3 so print statement must have parentheses and you have to just use `input()` instead of `raw_input()`.

```
import sys 
import calendar

trueVal = "yes"
while trueVal ==  "yes":  
    try:
        yy = int(input("Enter year: ")) 
        mm = int(input("Enter month: "))
        print(calendar.month(yy, mm))#returns the result

        trueVal = input("Would you like to view another calendar? Type yes if you do, no to exit program: ")


    except ValueError:
        print("Oops!  That was not an integer.  Try again...")
```

Comment: thank you ;-; but theres this thing abt the except, it says "no exception types specified. what does that mean?

Comment: it runs but, for academic sake, just in case its in the exam, i would love to know why it is so

Comment: @RaichiTakashita you are welcome, you don't have to specify the exception, writing it as ( exception: ) will catch all errors which in your case are numbers and letters and while you are adding ( int() ) on the input so you must have integer or the program will not work

Comment: @abdulla-alajami thank you very much, i am able to reach the deadline ;-; thank you

Comment: @RaichiTakashita you are welcome :)  please mark as correct, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `try/except` block, always together:

```
while trueVal ==  'yes' :  
    try:
        yy = int(input("Enter year: ")) 
        mm = int(input("Enter month: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Oops!  That was not an integer.  Try again...")
```

Comment: i tried the raw_input but it doesn't read it ;-; im using python 3.5

Comment: it says, "undefined variable 'raw_input' " ;-;

Comment: There  is no `raw_input` in python 3. Use `input()`

Comment: sorry @DanielSanchez it won't accept the edit because it must be at least 7 characters

Comment: @abdulla-alajmi, check how to edit because putting what you did in the edit with an **EDIT** tag is not what is meant to be

Comment: @DanielSanchez what I added is 2 characters: 1- "("  2- ")" , and it will not accept it I as I mentioned